# How to get the value of variable which has been posted via ajax to the controller?

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have the following code:

```
$('.pPage').click(function(){         
    var recordsPerPage = $(this).attr('id');
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        url: "backOfficeUsers/displayAllUsers",
        data: { value: recordsPerPage }
    }).done(function( msg ) {
        alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
    });
});
```

I need to manipulate recordsPerPage variable in my controller. How can I accept the value of this variable in my controller and use it in my php?

Here is the code for the controller:

```
public function displayAllUsers()
{
    $currentUser = $this->isLoggedIn();
    $this->load->model('backOfficeUsersModel');
    $this->db->order_by('userid');

    $myrec = $this->input->post('value');
    $recordsPerPage = $myrec; 

    $limit = $recordsPerPage;
    $offset = 3;

    $offset = $this->uri->segment(3);
    $this->db->limit($limit, $offset);

    $data['users'] = $this->backOfficeUsersModel->get();

    $totalresults = $this->db->get('back_office_users')->num_rows();

    //initializing & configuring paging
    $this->load->library('pagination');
    $config['base_url'] = site_url('/backOfficeUsers/displayAllUsers');
    $config['total_rows'] = $totalresults;
    $config['per_page'] = $limit;
    $config['uri_segment'] = 3;
    $config['full_tag_open'] = '<div class="dataTables_paginate paging_bootstrap pagination"><ul>';
    $config['full_tag_close'] = '</ul></div>';
    $config['cur_tag_open'] = '<li><a href=# style="color:#ffffff; background-color:#258BB5;">';
    $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a></li>';
    $config['num_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';

    $this->pagination->initialize($config); 

    $data['main_content'] = 'bousers/users';
    $data['title'] = 'Back Office Users';
    $errorMessage = FALSE;

    $this->load->vars($data,$errorMessage);
    $this->load->vars($currentUser);
    $this->load->view('backOffice/template');

} // end of function displayAllUsers
```

Comment: Probably not conventional CI but `$_POST['value']` should work

Comment: Doesnt work. $_post['value'] print error

Comment: PHP variables are case senstive. $_post!==$_POST. Phil is right from a non-conventional CodeIgniter standpoint. From a CodeIgniter standpoint, the equivalent is `$this->input->post("value");`

Comment: code:  echo $_POST['value']; die(); results with following error:A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined index: value

Filename: controllers/backOfficeUsers.php

Line Number: 18

Comment: @Zoran Obviously you'd need to check if it was a POST request and the `value` index was in the `$_POST` array

Answer (score 1):

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/input.html

```
$this->input->post('value');
```

Comment: Print empty value...any idea? If i console.log the value before the ajax call i get the value in console...

Comment: Main post has been just edited. Hopefully someone can spot the mistake. Here is 5:05 AM, and staring at this 5 hours now...

Answer (score 0):

Try to get the value using  `$_REQUEST['value'];` Hopefully this will work